# Wildfly timer service- cannot create table for timer persistence

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jboss, wildfly

I am using Wildfly-8.0.0.Final and I tried to configure timer service datastore based on PostgreSQL datasouce according to the following [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/EJB3+Clustered+Database+Timers) :

```
<timer-service thread-pool-name="timer" default-data-store="clustered-store">
    <data-stores>
        <database-data-store name="clustered-store" datasource-jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" partition="timer"/>
    </data-stores>
</timer-service>
```

but I am getting following error:

```
16:49:06,280 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS014263: Cannot create table for timer persistence: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: type "long" does not exist
```

When I am using the same datasource in the application (Hibernate, JPA) it works fine.

Could someone help me with solving this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation you cited the SQL statements for creating the timer database are stored in `modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as/ejb3/main/timers/timer-sql.properties`.

Opening that file, you'll see that there is no Postgres-specific SQL statement, so apparently WildFly uses the default, and Postgres chokes on the unknown column type `LONG`.

Try changing `LONG` to `BIGINT`, or add a new property `create-table.postgresql` with the modified statement.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I added new entry called `create-table.postgresql` and added `database="postgresql"` property to `database-data-store` entry in standalone.xml configuration file.

Comment: Relation was successfully created, but now I am getting two more errors when I start server: `relation "jboss_ejb_timer" already exists` and `column index is out of range: 1, columns count: 0`. Why it doesn't see that this relation was already created?

Comment: OK, the problem was solved by modifying timer-sql.properties file. Here is the gist for Wildfly 8.0.0.Final and postgresql database: https://gist.github.com/kkrol89/c37ddda12b6b342f076c